# Add dynamic autoplay to ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add active class one `li` to another `li` every 30 seconds?

I am using the following jQuery to autoplay the `li`:

```
setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
       }, 3000);
        function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
```

How can I add `active` class to `li`

My HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 30 sec then its should be `setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
       }, 30000);`

Comment: i want to add active class to every li

Comment: What are you trying to do? Should all `li` items have the class active after 120 seconds? Or can there be only one active clas at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8cLe/)

```
setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
   }, 3000);
    function moveRight() {
        var len=$('li');
        var i=1;
        $('li').each(function(){
            i++;
             if($(this).attr('class')=="active")
             {
                 $(this).next('li').addClass('active');
                 $(this).removeClass('active');
                 return false;
             }
            if(len.length==i)
            {
                $('li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: yep steve what help you need

Comment: if current li is active means based on the current li id="onediv", i need to show <div id="onediv"></div>

Comment: Crap, was just about to post almost the same :P ah well, +1 to you sir.

Comment: id="onediv"? where is it in your html?

Comment: simply im asking  how to do tat

Comment: instead of class active by using id onediv.Is it what you are asking?

Comment: Do you want below divs to be displayed in the same order as li?

Comment: s , when li is active to that relevant div , chk tis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910694/how-to-find-active-class-data-id

Comment: Check this fiddle @SteveBals http://jsfiddle.net/T8cLe/2/ .Since its not good to use same id name to two elements i am using a little trick which will identify the corresponding div