# how to find active class data-id

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="deal-menu">
   <li class="active" data-id="today-spl"><a href="#" class="first">Special<span class="active"></span></a></li>
   <li class="" data-id="today-deal"><a href="#">Deal</a><span></span></li>
   <li class="" data-id="today-spl"><a href="#" class="last">TDeal<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

my jquery code is

```
function addcls() {
        var current = $('.deal-menu li.active').removeClass('active'),
            next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.siblings().filter(':first');
        next.addClass('active');
        var val = $(this).data("id");
        alert(val);
    };

 setInterval(function () {
        addcls();
       }, 3000);
```

i need to find the active class data-id value , its showing undefined value

Comment: It should work.
Are you sure that $(this), is the good element you want ?
Try to console.log it for check that.

Comment: You can try to use `$(this).attr('data-id')` too.

Comment: You add active class to `next` so use `next.data("id");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
$('li.active').data('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $('li.active').attr('data-id');
alert(val);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHdN9/

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can also use:

```
var val = next.attr('data-id');
```

Because you assign the class active to the object 'next'

Answer (score 0):

You already have your target inside a variable, so use it :

```
var val = next.addClass('active').data("id");
```

`$(this)` in your case is `window` since you're in a function called by a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alert($(".active").attr(" data-id"));
```